# Flutter - HttpClient works on apps, but not browser. .NET Core 3.1 WebAPI + Flutter2

Tags: c#, flutter

I have a very simple WebAPI that is just the default for .NET Core 3.1. I'm using a certificate that is self-signed with .NET Core. When I do the network requests for macOS built using Flutter 2 everything works just fine. However, if I debug in Chrome, it doesn't work. Here's the Flutter 2 code that I'm using:

```
Future<int> getElements() async {
    print("getting weatherforecast");
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client
        .getUrl(Uri.parse("https://localhost:5001/weatherforecast"))
        .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
      // Optionally set up headers...
      // Optionally write to the request object...
      // Then call close.
      return request.close();
    }).then((HttpClientResponse response) {
      // Process the response.
      print(response.toString());
    });
    return 1;
  }
```

The API:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
```

I've tried adding print messages, but it doesn't seem to execute anything within the httpclient. I see no network traffic from the browser in the debug tools to send the requests either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to add a different library as HttpClient doesn't do browser requests, so I imported http_client via:

```
flutter pub add http_client
```

Then changed my request and imports to:

```
import 'package:http_client/browser.dart' as http;
...
Future<int> getElements() async {
    print("getting weatherforecast");

    http.BrowserClient client = new http.BrowserClient();
    var rs = await client
        .send(http.Request('GET', "https://localhost:5001/weatherforecast"));
    final textContent = await rs.readAsString();
    print(textContent);
    return 1;
  }
```

Comment: This does not provide HttpClient functionality as listed in the question. It's a dumbed down client.